# C# Data Structures for "Home Folder" - should this be its own entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In my application I have Folders that can contain other Folders.  They have all sorts of properties like this:

```
public class Folder
    {
        public Folder()
        {
            Sets = new Collection<Set>();
            Folders = new Collection<Folder>();
            Stage = Stage.one;
            IsArchived = false;
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            }

        // Primitive Properties 

        [Required]
        [Key]
        public virtual int FolderId { get; set; }

        public virtual int? ParentFolderId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentFolderId")]
        public virtual Folder ParentFolder { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual string Details { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Stage Stage { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual bool IsArchived { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FolderId")]
        public virtual ICollection<Set> Sets { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentFolderId")]
        public virtual ICollection<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

    }
```

Now, each User of the application has a "Home Folder" - a starting point.  The Home Folder doesn't need half of the above properties however.  I figure I have two options:

1) Use this entity and just add "isHomeFolder" as a property.  This is simple but means I'll be sending blank [Required] properties over the wire for JSON requests - Home Folders don't have a title, can't be archived, etc.

2) Create another entity with just the required fields and duplicate the required properties there.  This just doesn't seem very DRY, but feels better than the first option.

As a beginner programmer I'm not sure if there are any other options.  Is there a standard approach/solution here?

In case it matters, I'm building on Entity Framework Code-First + WebAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many home folders you are going to have compared to total number of folders. If you are going to have a lot more second level folders than home folders (and you most probably will) then why bother implementing another structure just for the sake of 10 or 20% or requests.

As for required fields being empty – just use some default value that will not be parsed on the server side and you’re good ;).

Answer (score 0):

> 2) Create another entity with just the required fields and duplicate
>   the required properties there. This just doesn't seem very DRY, but
>   feels better than the first option.

This is why ViewModel is important to avoid unnecessary (over) posting, posting values that you do not need. Also, to avoid the required fields in your entity where you would not want them or that they do not apply for "a specific view". An entity does not necessarily translate into a single view. Your case is one living example of it.

> Is there a standard approach/solution here?

As I've mentioned, create a viewmodel and copy only the properties that you need to capture inputs for. This is not repeating yourself, even if you put dataannotations on the same properties. The data annotations on your viewmodel is for the **view validation**. The annotations on your entity is for **domain validation**. That is not repeating, IMO, as your UI is a different layer than your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create a class which contains the common properties. Then you can use two classes that implement inheritance from the the first one.